# How to pass a string to HttpPost to include it as a form in Android

Tags: android, http-post

I have this string(postInfo):

```
"Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded&grant_type=refresh_token
&refresh_token=1/bNKLGjsbgYwkNytEwpNhgfTyuDs34Klkjtqp2AZKnqs&
client_secret=mySecret&client_id=my_id.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

I need to be able to send it into `HttpPost` in order to do its works, etc. I've been testing it out in Android, but it will not work unless it is a key value pair. I would just parse it if the string will always be the same, but I cannot guarantee that. While testing I realized why it has not been working. It is not included as a form in the body of the request. Interestingly enough, in iOs it does do this without much work. Here is my java:

```
public String post(String leUri, String data) {
        /*=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token*/
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(leUri);
            try {               
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postInfo));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return "An Error Ocurred";
        }
             try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        /*...*/
```

It does not appear as a form. How can I make it do so? I must be missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must split your postInfo as below and check the encoding website is taking for the post. Usually it is UTF-8

//set Content Type

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

// Add your data

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity("grant_type=refresh_token
&refresh_token=1/bNKLGjsbgYwkNytEwpNhgfTyuDs34Klkjtqp2AZKnqs&
client_secret=mySecret&client_id=my_id.apps.googleusercontent.com", "UTF-8"));